# Convert double for loop with break to list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a type something like this:

```
class T:
    id: int
    data: Any
```

I have a list of Ts with unique ids. I am provided another list of Ts with new data. So I want a new list that replaces any of the items where I have a new T with that new T.

```
current = [T(1), T(2), T(3)]
new = [T(2)*]

output = [T(1), T(2)*, T(3)]
```

I have a working double for loop with a break that I'm trying to turn into a list comprehension if it's cleaner.

```
output = []

for item in current_items:
    for new_item in new_items:
        if new_item.id == item.id:
            item = new_item
            break
    output.append(item)
```

This is what I tried but without the ability to break the inner loop after performing the if condition it obviously doesn't work.

```
output = [
    new_item if new_item.id == item.id else item
    for item in current_items            
    for new_item in new_items
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's feed `next` a generator expression finding elements in `b` with the same `id` as the current element in `a`, and default to the current element in `a` if no matching `id` is found in `b`.

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass
... class T(object):
...   id: int
...   name: str
... 
>>> a = [T(1, "foo"), T(2, "bar"), T(3, "baz")]
>>> b = [T(2, "wooble")]
>>> [next((y for y in b if y.id == x.id), x) for x in a] 
[T(id=1, name='foo'), T(id=2, name='wooble'), T(id=3, name='baz')]
```

Using `next` will replicate the behavior of your loop with a break on finding a match. The entire `b` list will only be iterated if a match isn't found.

If we didn't care about efficiency, we *could* generate a list of all matching items in `b` and then take the first one if it's not empty.

```
[c[0] if (c := [y for y in b if y.id == x.id]) else x for x in a]
```

But that both looks uglier and is potentially less efficient both in terms of runtime complexity and space, as it generates a bunch of useless lists.

Comment: Ooh a generator comprehension. I didn't know about those. I use list, dict, and set comprehensions but didn't know one could create a generator like that. 
Then to use it with a next that will try and get a value and either succeed or default to the existing value! Inspired. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing is setting the `output` to be new_items that are in the current items. I would suggest creating a set of current item ids and then just filtering new items that are in that `set`.

```
current_item_ids = {
    item.id
    for item in current_items
}

output = [
    item
    for item in new_items
    if item in current_item_ids
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that works. I need the old list updated with new entries. I think that only gets me the new entries.